# With unix script, how to check on s3 bucket that required number (10) of files are available,size

Tags: bash, unix

With `Unix` script, how to check on `s3 bucket` that required number (10) of files are available, if available then all 10 files sizes are greater than 0 KB.
If any file/s is/are missing we should log the same and notify Source team.
If any file/s is/are size is 0 KB we should log the same and notify Source team.

I created one `fileslist.txt` file which will have 10 expected files names to check.
Then used below `awk` to get `aws` files list

```
s3_files=$(aws s3 ls $SrcDir/ | awk '{print $4}')
```

Then unable move ahead to validate files availability, size.

Comment: Thanks to show us sample input, expected output

Comment: One option might be to `diff` the sorted fileslist.txt and the sorted output from your aws s3 file listing.  Something like: `diff <(sort fileslist.txt) <(aws s3 ls "$SrcDir | awk '!/PRE/ && $3>0 {print $4}' | sort)`

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect to notify Source team?

You could try a bash script such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
SrcDir="s3://.../"
s3_files=$(aws s3 ls $SrcDir/ | awk '{print $4}')

# check if all the expected files are present:
echo "Checking for expected files in S3 bucket..."
for file in $(cat filelist.txt); 
do
    if [[ ! "$s3_files" =~ "$file" ]]; then
        echo "$file is missing from S3 bucket"
    fi
done

# check the size of files
echo "Checking size of the files..."
for file in $(cat filelist.txt); 
do
    size=$(aws s3 ls $SrcDir/$file | awk '{print $3}')
    if [[ $size -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "$file size is 0 KB"
    fi
done
```

and retreive `echo` message for the source team